# Initialise a page factory in a step defs file

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I try to enter the code below into the stepdefs file for my feature

```
var page = new AccountPage();
PageFactory.InitElements(DriverContext.Driver, page);
```

but it complains wherever i place it, unless i place it in the Given statement like this

```
[Given(@"the user is on the Accounts page")]
public void GivenTheUserIsOnTheAccountsPage()
{
    var page = new AccountPage();
    PageFactory.InitElements(DriverContext.Driver, page);
    AccountPage.AccountSectionClick();
}
```

**Edit**

Ok i have this in the POM file

```
public class AccountPage : BasePage
{
    public AccountPage()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(DriverContext.Driver, this);
    }
```

and this in my stepdefs

```
AccountPage page = new AccountPage();
```

but when i use the 'page' command it doesnt give me a list of methods

Comment: you should provide details of what the error is and where it comes from. It looks like you are using a static method on the `AccountPage` so it might also help to show the code for that object if the error is in there.

Answer (score 0):

does changing to this help?:

```
[Given(@"the user is on the Accounts page")]
public void GivenTheUserIsOnTheAccountsPage()
{
    var page = new AccountPage();
    PageFactory.InitElements(DriverContext.Driver, page);
    page.AccountSectionClick();
}
```

I'm guessing as in your edit you still don't really give enough detail as you just show that your class inherits from a base page and give no indication where the method `AccountSectionClick` is defined.

Imagine you are reading the question without any other knowledge of your code and try to make sure that there is enough information to be able to provide an answer.